# How can I find a User's computer manufacture and model number by having the user use a web application?

Tags: java

I want to have a person run a program on my website.

The program would scan for the  computer's model name and manufacture

Would there be any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Not without installing some plugin, like Flash, Applet, Silverlight.

You can glean some information from the HTTP Header "User-Agent", but it's not reliable as web browsers have been know to spoof the value.

Answer (score 2):

The computer's manufacturer and serial number is not available in a regular web browser.

The only information available about the user's computer is that which is sent in the HTTP request headers: have a look at what your computer is sending. And even then, these can be trivially manipulated, so you can't rely upon their contents.

If you need this info, you could maybe:

- Ask them to enter it manually (don't underestimate the low-tech solution)
- Get them to upload a photo and then use Mechanical Turk to "automatically" identify it.